# Install Synaptics Driver

Tags: windows-8.1, synaptics-touchpad

I have installed the Synaptics Touchpad driver, version 18.1.3.

I did this by clicking setup:

[image]

The wizard appeared to install my driver okay:

[image]

However, following a reboot, the driver appears to be provided by microsoft:

[image]

[image]

I want that driver to be provided by Synaptic.

Also, where can I access synaptic's control interface? No applications have been installed, nothing in my tray, nothing I can use to troubleshoot or change my trackpad's settings (whole reason I'm installing synaptic, supported by my manufacturer)

Update:

No Synaptic devices in any menus in device manager!

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsTri.png): [image: no synaptics]

Comment: (Also, apologies but I cannot post more than 2 links or any images on this site until I have more rep, so if someone with more rep could embed these images that would be fab. Consider upvoting just so I can upload images in future? It is a clear question I would hope... Thanks) Update, thanks Rsya Studios

Comment: Now that's interesting. Are you sure the driver is for your computer? What model is it?

Comment: Can you move your trackpoint or touchpad now?

Comment: @Bilo yeah, the trackpad appears to be using this microsoft driver

Comment: @RsyaStudios http://www.toshiba.co.uk/laptops/satellite/s50-b/satellite-s50-b-15q/ you can search for model-centric drivers here http://www.toshiba.co.uk/innovation/download_drivers_bios.jsp?service=UK unfortunately I cannot link to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use "Update Driver" to manually specify the driver to use for the device.

- On the **Driver** tab of the device properties window, click on **Update Driver**. Select **Browse my computer for driver software**, then select **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer**.
- If the correct driver is listed, select it. If not, uncheck **Show compatible hardware**, select **Synaptics** for the manufacturer, and select the correct driver. The correct driver should then be used for the trackpad. (You may need to restart your computer.)

Comment: You're onto something there...I have three synaptic drivers to choose from:

Synaptics PS/2 PortCompatible TouchPad | Synaptics PS/2 Port Touchpad | Synaptics SMBus Touchpad |

Which should I choose?

Comment: Try the second one and see if you get full functionality. If not, try the first one.